# Upgrade gear ratio

Tags: gears

I have a triple chainset 50*39*30*,and 9speed cassette.Could I upgrade these to a 52*chainset and a 10speed cassette,without changing the chain or derailleur.TIA

Comment: If you go from 9 speed to 10 speed you have to change the rear shifter.

Answer (score 1):

52 tooth chainring, no problem but the difference is kind of small and not necessarily worth the trouble.

10 speed cassette, for road bikes the same derailleur works but you need narrower chain and shifter with 10 speed indexing.